# Oxid: Way to develop Mail Template without order

Tags: email, templates

i was wondering if there is any smart way to develop and edit email templates in oxid without triggering an order each time. I was thinking of something like a custom controller to access via browser to edit and analyse the output more easily.
Has anyone ever done something like that? I just stuck in the core code where the email is generated and am not able to recreate that behaviour in my own controller.

Thanks a lot.
Bastian

Answer (score 1):

there is no such function yet,
but you can use a module for developers, which keeps your basket after placing the order, so you can go back to the last step and place the same order again and again without processing first 4 steps.
https://github.com/vanilla-thunder/vt-devutils